# How to force JSonSerialiser to handle reference loops?

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to configure the SignalR JSon serializer to handle reference loops in my objects graph.
I have seen similar questions on SO, and borrowed the code below from there.

Following is the relevant part of the **ConfigureServices** method:

```
 services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(options =>
                {
                    options.PayloadSerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
                    options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
                });
```

Unfortunately, even with this configuration, trying to send data on the wire throws the following exception:

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'Vehicule' with type 'A.B.C.Vehicle'. Path ...

Obviously this code is not enough, but I can't figure out what to do.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This only covers SignalR. Are you sure the error is actually coming from communication via SignalR? If you're calling an action method at any point, you'll still have issues there.

Comment: I should have looked at the stack trace more carefully. I am indeed using JsonConvert.SerializeObject by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Add ShouldSerializePROPERTYNAME entry to your model source file:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeVehicule()
{
    return false;
}
```

or apply the attribute `[JsonIgnore]` to Vehicule.

This tells Json to skip it.